# Using R for an artificial neural network (ANN)? Or other frameworks?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm planning on starting a ANN classification project pretty soon. It will use 15 input variables (medical data with 25k records) to predict an outcome. I have been following the ML course on Coursera, where Octave is used, but I'm used to `R`. I've been reading about ANN in `R` and I got the feeling the solutions are not optimal. Main source of worry: [this thread](http://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-the-black-box-learning-challenge/forums/t/4403/mlp-with-sigmoid-units-and-three-hidden-layers?page=1). Here it is said that `R` implementations of ANN are not great, and other frameworks are 'better'/faster.

That's why I've been looking into Encog, and Encog Workbench, which is pretty neat. But still, using R would be nice. I could also consider using Octave.

Can you comment on the quality of the `R` ANN frameworks? Would you advice me to still use `R`? I really need the best accuracy I can get, as these data are most likely not be perfect.

Comment: I think for 15 inputs and 25k instances almost every standard library should be OK, even in R. If you really need high performance libraries: take a look at pylearn2 (Python), EBLearn (C++) or Torch7 (Lua). Other widely used libraries are PyBrain (Python), FANN (C and bindings for almost everything) and Encog (Java, C#).

Comment: It's not about performance, it's about accuracy, getting the best predictions from the network as possible. You don't think that would be different between these libraries? Of course if you just use the same settings on the networks you'd expect the same results, but then I don't understand why people in that thread complain the  `R` libraries aren't as good?

Comment: I don't know the R libraries. My guess would be that they havn't got very effective optimization algorithms like e.g. Levenberg-Marquardt. In this case you could also consider using a library like OpenANN (C++, https://github.com/OpenANN/OpenANN). Disclaimer: I am one of the developers and it is still in beta phase.

Comment: As far as I can tell, encog is a lot more accurate. I need to do a proper test, but trying the 'Abalone' dataset resulted in 82% acc for `nnet` in `R` and 96.8 for encog in 4k iterations. Might be some settings but still...

Comment: Everything that has to do with neural networks depends on settings: the choice of the error function, activation functions, number of nodes, optimization algorithm... If you don't know what you are doing, SVMs will usually be much easier to handle.

Comment: TensorFlow and Keras are two modern, prominent options in Python.